# How to override the onbackpressed event for Dialog box in android?

Tags: android

In android, how can you override the onbackpressed event for Dialog boxes?

Currently if I press back, it will dismiss it...

Thanks.

Comment: I got it working now. The answer is from the duplicate thread.

Answer (score 2):

You can just  set

```
mDialog.setCancellable(false);
```

Where mDialog is the dialog object.